# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format'

Tags: ios, layout, compiler-errors, constraints, autolayout

I have a subview that I want to keep stops during rotating screen, so I decided to put the NSLayoutConstraint type:


Trailing Space to Superview

Top Space to Superview

Button Space to Superview

I'm in a subclass of UITableViewCell. I wrote the code but I get the following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
 self is not a key in the views dictionary. 
 H:[self.arrows]-5-|
```

My code in CustomCell.m is:

```
 self.arrows = [[Arrows alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.bounds.size.width-30, self.bounds.origin.y+4, 30, self.contentView.bounds.size.height-4)];

 NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.arrows, self.contentView);
 NSMutableArray * constraint=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 [constraint addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:  [self.arrows]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
 [constraint addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-1-[self.arrows]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
 [constraint addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[V: [self.arrows]-1-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
 [self.arrows addConstraints:constraint];
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

It looks like that the autolayout visual format parsing engine is interpreting the "`.`" in your VFL constraint to be a keyPath instead of a key like it's using `valueForKeyPath:`.

`NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(...)` will take whatever your parameter is in the parenthesis and translate it into a literal key with the object as the value (in your case: `@{"self.arrow" : self.arrow}`).  In the case of the VFL, autolayout is thinking that you have a key named `self` in your view dictionary with a subdictionary (or subobject) that has a key of `arrow`,

```
@{
   @"self" : @{ @"arrow" : self.arrow }
}
```

when you literally wanted the system to interpret your key as "`self.arrow`".

Usually, when I'm using a instance variables getter like this, I typically end up creating my own dictionary instead of using `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(...)` like so:

```
NSDictionary *views = @{ @"arrowView" : self.arrow }
```

or

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_arrow);
```

Which would allow you to use the view in your VFL without the self and you still know what you're talking about:

```
NSArray *arrowHorizConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[arrowView]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views];
```

or

```
NSArray *arrowHorizConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[_arrow]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views];
```

As a general rule, I've learned not to have dictionary keys with a dot (`.`) in them to avoid any system confusion or debugging nightmares.

Comment: Pretty ridiculous that the docs give examples of using `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` to create the dictionary, but don't mention that it won't work with any property or IBOutlets

Comment: Jonathan, I was pretty confused by this myself. The docs specifically state to use that method. I just figured it was smart enough to remove the self. part of the key automatically.

Comment: "Pretty ridiculous" is... the understatement of the week.

Answer (score 7):

My trick is to simply declare a local variable that's just another pointer to the property, and put it in the `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings`.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong) UIButton *myButton;
@property (strong) UILabel *myLabel;
@end

...

UIButton *myButtonP = self.myButton;
UILabel *theLabelP = self.myLabel;
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myButtonP, myLabelP);
```

The `P` suffix is for "pointer".

Comment: This negates the point of NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings, which is to make things shorter. Why not use `NSDictionary *views = @{@"myButton":self.myButton, @"myLabel":self.myLabel}` instead? It's shorter.

Comment: It doesn't negate the point at all, if you have a long list of other views and want to insert a reference to `self.view`.

Comment: why do this instead of using _myButton and _myLabel? or synthesise to name ivars differently?

Comment: Because you might not want to change your coding style just for the sake of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to avoid the getters for variables from your own class and redefine variables from superclasses as local variables. A solution for your example is

```
UIView *contentView = self.contentView;
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_arrows, contentView);
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you add the constraints after adding the required subview to your main view.It took a while get knowledge relating to this issue .