# Remove Auto-Layout Constraints for Specific Object

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a `UIImageView` embedded in a `UIView`. My entire app uses `AutoLayout`, but I want to  remove `constraints` for the `UIImageView`. `Xcode` will not allow me to delete the `constraints`, is there a way to disable them for a specific object, set them to zero, something?

Comment: If you remove the constraints, how can the image view be displayed? How will the layout engine know where to put it? You have to have enough constraint information to unambiguously lay out the whole view. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to resize the image view with gestures. The auto layout constraints won't allow pinch gestures to make the image view smaller.

Comment: Just to be clear .. for a particular XIB file. To **turn off** autolayout (ie to "remove the Constraints thingy") just click to ShowFileInspector, and simply uncheck "autolayout". Each item on the xib will now work like the "old" style (with the "sticky arrows" and so on.)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I agree Xcode auto-layout is horrible to use if you want something particular...

What I use to remove constraints programatically:

```
[detailsPhotoView removeConstraints:detailsPhotoView.constraints];
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I have removed all constraints from a view and re-set them using the visual format language; The code above is required to remove constraints before specifying your own, otherwise xcode will keep complaining

Comment: Also remember one thing, if you are trying to remove a constraint from a UIImageView then make sure you add that view by code. Don't use IBoutlet as that seems to have no effect at all on your setFrame code. I just ran into this crap.

Answer (score 26):

In XCode 5 there is an option while editing constraints 'Remove at build time'.  If this is enabled the constraint will automatically be removed during run-time.  The option is there to keep Interface Builder happy if you don't want particular constraints.

Comment: Best answer, short and precise.

Comment: In XCode 6 this is now called Intrinsic Size with the option set to Placeholder.

Answer (score 9):

There are two distinct issues here:

1. How to use Xcode to setup a UIImageView without constraints
2. How to allow the UIImageView to be panned and/or resized when its layout is handled by constraints.

Regarding (1), jturton is correct. As long as you have enabled auto layout within Xcode, Xcode will guarantee/require that there are sufficient constraints to uniquely determine the size and location of your view.

If you have not manually specified enough constraints in Xcode (via the "user constraints" that appear in blue in the layout inspector), then Xcode will add new constraints that it guesses (which appear in purple) until there are sufficient constraints to determine the layout.

If the UIImageView had no constraints on it, its layout would not be determined, so you cannot set that up in Xcode. To fix this, what you should do is use Xcode to setup IBOutlets to all the constraints you want to remove, and then in your UIView's awakeFromNib: or in your UIViewController's viewDidLoad: you manually remove the constraints by calling removeConstraints:.

However, now your UIImageView's layout is underdetermined. So at this point you will want to manually add new constraints that will allow you to move and resize the UIImageView, which brings us to question (2).

Regarding (2), how to resize & move a view whose layout is determined by constraints, the answer is to setup gesture recognizers as usual to detect the pinch & pan gestures, but instead of those gesture recognizers calling setFrame: to modify the view, they should modify the `constant` parameter of a NSLayoutConstraint that determines the frame of the UIImageView and then call layoutIfNeeded:, which will cause the layout system to immediately translate that modified constraint into a new frame.

So, for instance, suppose you want to manipulate the UIImageView with a set of layout constraints that were very similar to familiar setFrame: calls. In that case, after removing the constraints setup by Xcode, you could add constraints to the view that specify its width, its height, and its space from the top and left of the superview. Then the action handler for your pan gesture recognizer, would just update the constant parameter of the pacer gesture recognizer, and your pinch gesture recognizer could just update the constant parameter of the height and width constraints.

Another way to do (2), which is the same under the hood but might be easier in practice, is to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES`. This will do two things. It will cause the auto layout system to automatically generate constraints in the view's superview based on the view's autoresizingMask. Second – crucially! – it will cause the layout system to automatically translate calls to setFrame: into modifications of those constraints.

Comment: There's one PITA about removing constraints: you need to remove a constraint from the view that "hosts" it. E.g. if you have and image view inside a scroll view and a constraint between them, then it's the scroll that hosts it. The constraint will not be present in image view's `constraints` property, calling `removeConstraint:` on the image view will be silently ignored, and there is no way to get the host view from a constraint itself. Thus you have to have outlets for both scroll view and the constraint and specifically call `[self.scrollView removeConstraint:self.constraint]`. Argh!

Answer (score 6):

You *can't* not have constraints - you must have enough constraints in place to unambiguously size and position every view

You *can* create a resizable view that is laid out using Autolayout.

For example, in your case, you can create positioning constraints - say, pin the centre of the image view horizontally and vertically in the centre of its superview.

You can also create size constraints, horizontally and vertically. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418834/ios-simple-autolayout-with-1-label-and-3-buttons/13422791#13422791) for how to do this. Create outlets to these two constraints (if using interface builder). You can have height and width constraints of a specific number, or use the multiplier to make a fixed aspect ratio.

In response to pinch gestures, you can adjust the `.constant` properties of the two size constraints, and call `setNeedsLayout`. This will resize your image view whilst keeping its centre pinned.

If you do the fixed aspect ratio suggestion above, resizing a view using constraints is actually much simpler than setting the frame.

Comment: I don't want to keep anything pinned within this container UIView. I want the imageView (the one within the UIView) to be able to be pinched, moved, panned etc. without pinning anything or having any size constraints. What constants would I set for that? I can't seem to achieve my immediate thought of removing all constrains.

Comment: If you want it to be moved as well as resized, then you need positioning constraints which you also have outlets to which you can modify in code in the same way as I describe the size constraints above. You _can't_ not have constraints - you must have enough constraints in place to unambiguously size and position every view.

Comment: Will you add this as an edit to you answer: you must have enough constraints in place to unambiguously size and position every view. Then I'll accept it.

Comment: unfortunately no, I had to remove auto-layout so the user could resize the imageView. I may try to add it in later. But your answer that they can't be completely removed appears totally correct. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This does not answer the question, and the suggestion that removing constraints is not legitimate is wrong. One might need to remove IB-generated constraints to replace them with ones that cannot be created in IB, or simply remove all constraints and use `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` instead.

Comment: @VadimYelagin I'm not sure what you mean. I'm saying you can't remove all constraints in IB (if you're using Autolayout) and I also talk about adding your own constraints in code. In what way am I not answering the question, and what specifically have I said that is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

you can call

```
[yourElement removeFromSuperview];
```

and then call

```
[yourSuperview addSubview:yourElement];
```

to remove all constraints from `yourElement` and add it back to the view.

It is worth mentioning that if you are doing the above on something like a UIView category or extension, you need to save a reference to the view's superview before removing from superview:

```
var theSuperview = self.superview
self.removeFromSuperview()
theSuperview?.addSubview(self)
```

You might also need to make yourElement strong instead of weak since removing from superview could potentially cause you to lose a reference to it.

Comment: I have a custom object object.view that just wouldn't follow the removeConstraints method. This solved it great. No warnings and behavior defined programmatically exactly as I had hoped. Thanks Adam!

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want to remove a view from a hierarchy, just call `[theView removeFromSuperview]`. Any constraints affecting it will also be removed.

However, sometimes you might also want to put a view back, having **temporarily** removed it.

To achieve this, I use the following category on `UIView`. It walks up the view hierarchy from a view `v` to some ultimate container view `c` (usually your view controller's root view) and removes constraints that are external to `v`. These are constraints that are siblings to `v`, rather than constraints that only affect `v`'s children. You can hide `v`.

```
-(NSArray*) stealExternalConstraintsUpToView: (UIView*) superview
{
    NSMutableArray *const constraints = [NSMutableArray new];

    UIView *searchView = self;
    while(searchView.superview && searchView!= superview)
    {
        searchView = searchView.superview;

        NSArray *const affectingConstraints =
        [searchView.constraints filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
         [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint, NSDictionary *bindings)
          {
              return constraint.firstItem == self || constraint.secondItem == self;
          }]];

        [searchView removeConstraints: affectingConstraints];
        [constraints addObjectsFromArray: affectingConstraints];
    }

    return constraints;
}
```

The method passes back the removed constraints in an array that you can keep somewhere so that later on you can add the constraints back.

Use it a bit like this…

```
NSArray *const removedConstraints = [viewToHide stealExternalConstraintsUpToView: self.view];
[viewToHide setHidden: YES];
```

And later on, put the constraints back.

As of iOS 8 you don't need to think about where the constraints should be put. Just use this…

```
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints: removedConstraints];
[viewToHide setHidden: NO];
```

With earlier versions of iOS you don't need to think hard about where to add the constraints back. Throw then in the controller's `self.view`. Provided constraints are in **a** superview of all the views that they affect, they will work.

```
[self.view addConstraints: removedConstraints];
[viewToHide setHidden: NO];
```

Comment: activateConstraints is available since iOS 8

Comment: @b.zdybowicz – thanks, have updated to make that explicit. Anyone can make edits, by the way – they're sometimes moderated, though.