# iOS: Simple AutoLayout with 1 Label and 3 Buttons

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm playing around with AutoLayout and am really banging my head against the wall for what seems like it ought to be an extremely simple solution.

1. I've got a vertical column of controls: 1 label and 3 buttons.
2. I want the label to be 40 pixels(points) tall and auto-size its width based on the width of its superview (standard spacing on left, top and right).
3. I want the 3 buttons to line up vertically below that label.
4. I would like their widths to auto-size just like the label.
5. I would like their spacing to be standard (aqua?) spacing (8 points, right?).
6. I would like the 3 buttons to be the same height.

I can get what I want to happen to work, but I keep getting errors in the console at runtime, and I'd like to figure out WHY I'm getting them and HOW to avoid getting them. I've watched the WWDC videos on AutoLayout, and here's what I've tried so far:

```
UILabel *label = [self Label];
MMGlossyButton *button1 = ...
MMGlossyButton *button2 = ...
MMGlossyButton *button3 = ...
[[self view] addConstraints:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[label]-|"
    options:0
    metrics:nil
    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];
[[self view] addConstraints:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[button1]-|"
    options:0
    metrics:nil
    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(new)]];
[[self view] addConstraints:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[button2]-|"
    options:0
    metrics:nil
    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(existing)]];
[[self view] addConstraints:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[button3]-|"
    options:0
    metrics:nil
    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(provider)]];
[[self view] addConstraints:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[label(40)]-[button1(>=25)]-[button2(==button1)]-[button3(==button1)]-|"
    options:0
    metrics:nil
    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label, button1, button2, button3)]];
```

So, this works for displaying the view in a dynamically-sized way, but the following error pops up in the console:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
        (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you 
               don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView 
               property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

// A whole bunch of constraint stuff that doesn't appear to be important...

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7554c40 V:[MMGlossyButton:0x7554b40(99)]>
```

So, the last bit appears to indicate that the first button I have on the view is statically sized to 99 points tall. 
Which is the size it has on the view. 
Which is completely arbitrary. 
Which I don't want assigned, but can't figure out a way to un-assign it.

Although I'm getting what I want (sort of, eventually), it seems to be a REALLY roundabout way to accomplish something that's pretty simple. Am I missing something basic about AutoLayout, or does its power require such complexity?

Comment: How are you adding the buttons and labels to the view in the first place? In the storyboard, or in code?

Comment: Also, the "whole bunch of constraint stuff that doesn't appear to be important" probably _is_, can you include it?

Comment: I could, but it's a TON of content, and it's just the constraints I'm defining in the code I show. Also, the buttons are placed on a XIB using IB. That's where the 99 point height comes from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are encountering errors because you are mixing and matching constraints generated in code with constraints added by interface builder. Interface builder doesn't let you generate an ambiguous layout, so almost by definition if you add additional constraints, you will get an `"Unable to simultaneously satisfy"` error, which is the downfall of many a marriage.

To resolve this you either need to define all the constraints you need in interface builder, or you need to mark specific ones as outlets and remove them in code before adding your own.

In your case, the constraints are simple enough to create in IB.

You can pin to a specific height by using this button in IB while your label is selected:

[image]

The one in the middle, that looks like a girder. This gives you the following useful menu:

[image]

Choosing one of these allows you to create a new constraint against the label, which you can then edit by selecting it:

[image]

You can then add your buttons, select all three of them and, using the same menu, create an equal heights constraint.

The constraints created in IB aren't particularly flexible, so if you do decide you need to create or modify them in code, it is best to create outlets to the particular constraints, and then either remove and re-create them, or modify the `constant` value at run time.

Comment: I think there may be bugs with Xcode or something. I'm following your instructions, which match my instincts, which match logic, but it just doesn't work. Unless, of course, there's something I don't know about when I switch the view's size from Retina 4 to Retina 3.5. I can get the layout working as I want with Retina 4, but when I then switch to Retina 3.5, a whole bunch of different constraints appear and the layout seems to be "frozen" just before changing the view's size. Thoughts?

Comment: My main thought is that constraint editing in IB is very poorly done! I did a sample project whilst answering this question, I didn't change between the two iPhone sizes though. I'll have a look when I'm back at my mac.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it's just me, or maybe it's Xcode. It seems difficult to isolate what is causing the problem. If I'm comfortable doing all of my constraints in code, but still want to do the original layout in IB, is that possible? How would I do that?

Comment: Changing from 3.5 to 4 inches makes no difference to the constraints in my sample project, they stay exactly the same. So I'm not sure what is going on with yours. I'm on Xcode 4.5.2. As for you other question, you can do it by removing and re-adding constraints but to be honest, by the time you've done all that, you might as well have built the whole thing in code.

Comment: For something like this, you're undoubtedly right. I'm worried, however, that AutoLayout just isn't going to be as user-friendly as it could be. In this scenario, I'll likely just avoid using a XIB altogether, but that's annoying, ya know? Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Upvoting this just for the ""Unable to simultaneously satisfy" error, which is the downfall of many a marriage." part. +1

Comment: What @mattcurtis said... :-)