# How to remove UITableViewCell NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint and Add my own to subviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, autolayout

What is the proper way to remove NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraints from UITableViewCell subviews and add my own constraints without seeing error messages in the simulator log?

For example, I want to dynamically change the size of a UILabel inside a UITableViewCell by adding a width constraint. I don't even know if this the preferred method of doing this. Is there some way for me to find the constraint and update that directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all of the constraints for an object, then add back in the ones you want.

To remove them:

```
[yourView removeConstraints:yourView.constraints];
```

Then you can manually add your own constraints.
([here is a more detailed link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13055845/793607) on adding view width constraints)

To just modify the existing constraints:

```
for(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in yourView.constraints) {
    //you can inspect these to see if their .firstAttribute or .secondAttribute correspond to the type of NSLayoutAttribute you are looking for.
 }
```

Comment: Are NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraints generated by IB not able to be seen in this way? When I inspect views.constraints inside the tableview cell and the cell.constraints, they seem to be blank.

Comment: Did you look at this answer?  It has a few ideas on autolayout options.  Also, if you remove all the visible constraints, you should be able to override ib one with your manually entered ones.