# What is the correct way to auto expand a UIButton to the width of an interface on orientation change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autoresizingmask

I am trying to automatically expand a UIButton width to the width of an interface upon orientation change.

Does anyone have working code for this? I have tried using AutoResizing mask, but perhaps I'm not using the correct one.

Comment: using constraints or autolayout.

Comment: Thanks Hector, do you have a code example?

Comment: Maybe this post would help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826878/creating-layout-constraints-programmatically

Comment: You could also override layoutSubviews in the ViewController, to position and resize manually (and if you need pixel precision). Though auto-layout is easier I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways of doing this. 
In your view controller sub class overrride [`-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a) or [`-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a)

You could also override [`-viewWillLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) and then adjust the frame depending on the orientation by querying [`self.interfaceOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/interfaceOrientation).

And change the size of the button in that method, either by adjusting the constraints or changing the frame of the button.