# AutoLayout for programmatically created uiview element

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

When i try to create an uiview with loading text and activityindicator, even though it looks centered in iphone 6, it is not centered in iphone 5.

How can i use auto layout for this programatically created UIView ?

I am trying to center this uiview in all screen sizes

```
boxView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: TableView.frame.midX - 60, y: TableView.frame.midY - 15, width: 180, height: 50))
boxView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
boxView.alpha = 0.5
boxView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

var activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)
activityView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
activityView.startAnimating()

var textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
textLabel.text = "Loading"

boxView.addSubview(activityView)
boxView.addSubview(textLabel)

TableView.addSubview(boxView)
```

EDIT: I tried this and it seems working good

```
var bounds: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        var width:CGFloat = bounds.size.width
        var height:CGFloat = bounds.size.height
        boxView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: width/2 - 90, y: height/2 - 100, width: 180, height: 50))
```

Comment: Why don't you use the interface builder and create the necessary constraints there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating layout constraints programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826878/creating-layout-constraints-programmatically)

Comment: You are using hardcoded frame co-ordinates to place view, this will not work for all the devices. You need to use Auto Layout. Please take some time and read about it, that will make life lot easier.

Comment: @nhgrif that question is for object-c not Swift