# How to specify constraints in iOS Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, constraints

I am a begineer to iOS App Development. Previously I had done Android Development. But I am finding it quite difficult to implement UI design in iOS compared to Android. I want to create UI design of this sort.

[image]

I want to place icons aligned left. And add new icons to left of the created ones. Also, I want to add a thumbnail gallery at the bottom of this sort at the bottom.

Can anyone guide how to begin this UI development in iOS? I searched for it, but I am not able to understand how to implement it.

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder and a storyboard or creating items programatically?

Comment: I am creating items programatically. @Paulw11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

and possible duplicate of

[How to Create layout constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651022/how-to-create-layout-constraints-programmatically)

[Creating layout constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826878/creating-layout-constraints-programmatically)