# iOS - set subview width to be the same as parent (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a storybaord with a `UIView` that has a class set to `MyView` (this class is defined as `@interface MyView : UIView`).

In class `MyView`, I have this construction:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{            

    [super awakeFromNib];

    [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyNib" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];

    [self addSubview:self.contentView];
}
```

It loads design from nib and add `contentView` to it. Now, how can I set `contentView` width to be the same as width of `self`? I have tried add constraint programatically under `addSubview` method, but app crashed.

So where should I add constraint and how the code should be?

Comment: no need of constraints for making wdith equal. YOu set the constraints properly for elements inside xib. You can just change the frame of the xib in the awake from nib method.

Comment: Why are you adding constraint in the code when you can set constraints in the interface builder?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Thanks... if you put this as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set constraints to make the width equal.

Just set the constraints for the elements in the xib so that they will get aligned according to their superview frame.

And you can set the xib view frame in the awakeFromNib method.

Answer (score 0):

You can make outlet of your xib view and then can set set constraints to programatically view accordingly to its parent view. you might have get idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31651348/5966706) It should work.

Comment: I have used this approach, but it crashed... I am not sure where I should add constraint, because in awakeFromNib, crash happens.

Comment: I am agree with @teja Nandamuri actually you can set your constraints in xib view and then in viewDidAppeare method you can add your child view with same width of your parent view frame width as constrains are execute after viewWillAppeare.