# how to set constraints programmatically in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to dynamically create a UIView at the bottom of the screen , which need to contain 4 buttons horizontally (eg. button1 , button2 , button3 , button4). And the problem is I couldnt able to set the constraints for it , could any one suggest me .

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please add some code. there is a pretty good explanation of setting constraints here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651022/how-to-create-layout-constraints-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to have 4 buttons, horizontally aligned, I would suggest you use a `UIStackView` with `vertical axis`. You can set its `contentMode` to be `Fill Equally` and add your 4 buttons as children to the `UIStackView`. Regarding your question "how to constraint a view programatically", this is how you can achieve this (this is just an example of a view constraint to the bottom of the screen with height equal to 80):

```
var yourView = UIView()
// Pin the leading edge of yourView  to the leading edge of the main view
yourView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor).active = true

// Pin the trailing edge of yourView to the leading trailing edge
yourView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor).active = true

// Pin the bottomedge of yourView to the margin's leading edge
yourView .bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor).active = true

// The height of your view
yourView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(80).active = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . could you please specify this in objective- c , sorry i am new to ios .