# How to create programatic autolayout in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I want to Displays the content (including image, title and description) in a table.
I am trying to set autolayout for same. but my image is getting shrink according to cell height.
But I want to show image as original (all images are of diff. height width)

```
 UIImageView *customImageView;
        UILabel *customLabel;


        customImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        customImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        customImageView.tag = indexPath.row + 100;
        customImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:customImageView];

        customLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        customLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        customLabel.tag =  indexPath.row + 500;
        customLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        customLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:customLabel];

        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customImageView, customLabel);
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[customImageView(160)]-[customLabel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-3-[customImageView]-3-|"                 options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-3-[customLabel]-3-|"                     options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

1.HOw can i show image as it is
2.how can I add another label for description below title label using constraints?
Can you please suggest some solution or guide me on this?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31651348/3338583

Comment: @SyedAliSalmanthat answer is not helpful for my question

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651022/how-to-create-layout-constraints-programmatically

Comment: To fix your image scaling problem, set the contentMode to UIViewContentModeCenter (unscaled) and set the compression resistance to high.

Answer (score 0):

All that you need is `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. ImageView's has implicit size. ImageViews take size based on the image set to them. When your cell contains the components with implicit sizes you can make use of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to tell the tableView to size the cell based on the size of imageView.

make sure you set the imageView's content mode set to `center`

**Code :**

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

Don't write height for row at indexPath :)

O/P:

[image]

Look at cell sizes. Changing their size automatically based on image.

**EDIT :**

Forgot to mention the only auto layout constraint added to imageView and cell are trailing, leading, top and bottom constraints with constant 0 to cell.

[image]