# How to add UIviews programmatically using auto-layouts parogramatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Hi I am trying to add `UIViews` programmatically using **Auto Layout**.

Here my main requirement is that I want to set the firstView(i.e `myView1`) trailing space to "30" and I want to set the second view (i.e `myView2`) to 30 distance from first view like image below.

For this I have written some code (using visual format and constraint with item format) but this is not working.

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIView *myView1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    myView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    myView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;  
    [self.view addSubview:myView1];

    UIView *myView2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    myView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    myView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;  
    [self.view addSubview:myView2];


    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[myView1(==50)]-50-|"
                               options:0
                               metrics:nil
                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView1)]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[myView2(==50)]-50-|"
                               options:0
                               metrics:nil
                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView2)]];

//Constraints with item formate
            NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-30.f];
            [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

            constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:50.0f];
            [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

           NSLayoutConstraint*constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-30.f];
          [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

           constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:50.0f];
          [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];


//Constraints with visual formate
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[myView1(==50)]-20-[myView(==50)]-30-|"
                               options:0
                               metrics:nil
                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView1,myView2)]];

}
```

[image]

Comment: you may try a wrapper https://github.com/robb/Cartography

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating layout constraints programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826878/creating-layout-constraints-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

Screenshot

[image]

And code with Visual Formatter language

```
UIView *myView1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
myView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
myView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:myView1];

UIView *myView2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
myView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
myView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:myView2];

NSDictionary * viewsDic = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView1,myView2);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[myView1(50)]-30-[myView2(50)]-30-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:viewsDic]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[myView1(50)]-30-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:viewsDic]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[myView2(50)]-30-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:viewsDic]];
```

**Update,code in item format**

```
UIView *myView1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
myView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
myView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:myView1];

UIView *myView2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
myView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
myView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:myView2];

//View2.width=50
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView2
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:0
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:50]];
//View2.height=50
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView2
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:0
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:50]];
//View2.traling = self.traling - 30
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView2
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:-30]];

//View2.bottom = self.bottom - 30
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView2
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:-30]];

//View1.width = 50
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:0
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:50]];
//View1.height=50
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:0
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:50]];

//View1.traling = View2.leading - 30
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:myView2
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:-30]];
//View1.bottom = self.bottom - 30
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView1
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:-30]];
```

Comment: yes your right but i want this answer in constarint with item formate

Comment: @Krish See,what I update.I suggest to use visual format language.It is short and clear