# How can I add a constraint to a label such that it is always 0 points away from a UITextView which is dynamic?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel, uitextview

I have a dynamic UITextView and need to add a UILabel right bellow. This label should always be 0 (touching) the bottom of the textView.

I have tried constraints like this but have not been able to make it work as intended.

```
self.dateOfComment.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 0).isActive = true
```

**How can I make this functionality work?**

I have [looked here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826878/creating-layout-constraints-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
self.lbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:textView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```